# Can I invoke a webservice with Apache Camel and return the response?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

This question might be a little abstract, but I'm trying to do something with `Apache Camel` and I'm stuck.

The basic scenario is this, I expose a webservice `A` through Camel, in this service, there is a content-based routing to decide if I have to invoke `B` or `C`, and I'd like to invoke the right one, and have the response from `B` or `C` to be the response of my service `A`

I have exposed the webservice already with `camel-cxf` and it works very well, but I don't know how to go about the routing after that, I have thought of this:

```
from("cxf:bean:myServiceA").choice()
    .when(new PredicateForServiceB())
        .process(new ProcessorForServiceB())
    .when(new PredicateForServiceC())
        .process(new ProcessorForServiceC())
    .otherwise()
    .endChoice()
.to("log:output");
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way or even if this is correct, but it's what I came up with.

Now I don't know how I would implement those processors, I could just create a normal invocation to the services and build the output, but I'd like to do it with the Camel infrastructure.

does anyone have any pointers on this? I'd be glad to provide more information if necessary

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "I could just create a normal invocation to the services and build the output, but I'd like to do it with the Camel infrastructure."?

Comment: What I meant is that I could do a HTTP Soap invocation by hand using URLConnection or any other thing, all inside a processor, but I wanted to use Camel's infrastructure to avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel provides the [Bean binding](https://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html), which you don't need to touch much of Camel API and focus on the business logic you need to in the POJO bean.
If you use [Processor API](https://camel.apache.org/processor.html), you can handle the Exchange yourself, then the response can be send back to client if you setup out message on the exchange.

Comment: That ended up being how I did it :)